# How to create a custom decimal format field?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I want to create a custom decimal format field in sharepoint with structure `#####.#####`. Example: If you enter `1.05` this field will return `00001.05000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 options there and indeed, the custom field is one of these options.

In order to create a SharePoint custom field, you can follow this link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417414(v=office.12).aspx

Your needs is quite easy to develop. The most part is to learn how to manage a sharePoint custom field.
In a custom field you'lle have two part :

- The code behind which define you custom control and his logic
- A definition in xml in order to declare your custom field and have the ability to use it in SharePoint

The second option would be to calculate your desired format and write it in another column.
You could program the logic to do this in a Workflow or in  Event Receiver.

I think the first option is the most appropriate.

Comment: I try to create 2 site column, first site column I use to get number from the user and the second ones I use Text Formula to take it to the new format I want

Comment: Great. Can you share the formula ?

Answer (score 1):

@thibault: Yes, Of course. I created a `Site Column` in `SharePoint 2013`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field
       ID="{90933566-01f5-43f2-b047-248d121f4d85}"
       Name="SiteColumn1"
       DisplayName="Site Column 1"
       Type="Number"   
       Required="FALSE"
       Group="Custom Site Columns">
  </Field>

  <Field
     ID="{3566F631-EFB1-4478-9DC0-FCA4F69A718E}"
     Name="decimalNumber"
     DisplayName="Site Column 2"
     Type="Calculated"
     Required="FALSE"
     ResultType="Text"
     Group="Custom Site Columns">
    <Formula>
      =TEXT([SiteColumn1],"000000.000000")
    </Formula>
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

After that, I created a `List` and take this `site column` into there. 
This is my solution.